# Django and Collectstatic Issue

Tags: django, collectstatic

I'm trying to deploy my `Django web Application (2.0.1)` thanks to `Nginx` and I'm getting an issue.

I configured the new Ubuntu server, add my Django Project and I downloaded nginx.

My Django project looks like :

```
Mysite
├── App1
├── App2
├── App3
├── lib
    ├── Global_variables.py
├── Mysite
    ├── settings.py
```

I have to make `collectstatic` with nginx, so I execute this command :

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

But into my settings.py file, I have :

```
#from django.conf import global_settings
import os, datetime
import lib.Global_variables
```

And this issue :

```
File "/var/www/Mysite/Mysite/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    import lib.Global_variables
ImportError: No module named lib.Global_variables
```

However my import seems to be right. Any idea ?

Comment: Hi! Try to add `__init__.py` to the lib folder. This will convert lib to python package.

Comment: It seems to work but I have some issues with modules installed into `INSTALLED_APPS`. I think you could add your message as an answer and I will validate it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make directory a python package you need to add inside this directory `__init__.py` file. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path